# How to register EF DbContext with NetTcpBinding WCF using DI (Castle Windsor WCFFacility)?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ef-code-first, castle-windsor

I'm using **EF6 CodeFirst** and **WCF 4.5** with **NetTcpBinding** and **BasicHttpBinding**. Also I'm using **Castle.Windsor** for DI.

I have the following architecture:

**MySolution.Core** (class library)
- Domain
-- (...domain classes...)
- Data
-- IRepository.cs

**MySolution.BusinessLogic** (class library)
- (...business logic classes...)

**MySolution.Data** (class library using EF6)
- Models
-- Mapping
-- MyContext.cs (MyContext : DbContext, IDbContext)
- EFRepository.cs (EFRepository : IRepository, where in constructor is injected IDbContext)
- IDbContext.cs

**MySolution.Services** (WCF Project hosted in IIS with http and net.tcp)
- AppCode
-- Initialization.cs (instead global.asax, to be used with netTcpBinding)
- Installers
-- BusinessLogicInstaller.cs
-- RepositoriesInstaller.cs
-- ServicesInstaller.cs

In AppCode/Initialization.cs I have:

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
container.Install(
new ServicesInstaller(),
new BusinessLogicInstaller(),
new RepositoriesInstaller());
```

And, inside Installers/RepositoriesInstaller.cs:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            // registration for EF context
            container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MySolution.Data")
                .InNamespace("MySolution.Data.Models")
                .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                .LifestylePerWcfOperation());

            // registration for EF repository classes
            container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MySolution.Data")
                .InNamespace("MySolution.Data")
                .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                .LifestyleTransient());
        }
```

ServicesInstaller and BusinessLogicInstaller register classes with LifestyleTransient.

Obs: The WCF must offer RESTful binding in the future.

My questions are:

1. If I use netTcpBinding, I cannot use LifestylePerWebRequest for DbContext, right?
2. It's safe and correct to use LifestylePerWcfOperation for the DbContext? If yes, is OK to use with BasicHttpBinding also? I don't find information explaining in detail the PerWcfOperation.
3. Is my architecture OK? Maybe I misunderstand some important concept with IoC/DI?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the code for LifestylePerWcfOperation it seems to be simply hooking into WCF's operation started and ended events so whether it is a netTcpBinding or basicHttpBinding shouldn't matter.   Given you do indeed need to spin up a context that lasts the lifetime of a request, that seems perfectly sensible to me.  Did you try it and have a problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Correct. In WCF, LifestylePerWebRequest only works for HTTP bindings where you have AspNetCompatibility enabled.
2. LifestylePerWcfOperation can be used with any WCF bindings.
3. Architecture looks pretty complex but whether it's OK or not depends on the scale and complexity of your application. Really impossible to answer that question sensibly without a ton more information. This sort of architecture is very decoupled and my first questions is whether it's over-engineered for the problem at hand and whether you're also at risk of having anemic domain model.